# Converting mobile dp font-size into desktop px value

Tags: css, resolution, font-size

I know, I know - I should not use px in my css for specifying font-size. I have an excuse though.

I'm writing a browser-based editor designed to visually create mobile content. I have a fixed-width 800*600px "canvas" that represents what would be visible on mobile device landscape viewport, and a bunch of toolbars around it (a bit like Photoshop).

There's a JSON format which my editor reads from and saves to, representing the mobile content. That JSON is then interpreted by the mobile app and appropriate content is displayed.

In this format, font-size is specified as an integer in dp units. Question: how would I convert that font-size to be displayed in my desktop web app (knowing that my "canvas" is 800*600 px)?

I found a hacky way of getting the PPI of my desktop browser, not sure if that's at all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using font size in px you can use em so that it will work on all devices and browsers on desktop

Comment: Thanks but em is relative to body font-size, so the issue of converting from dp still stands. I'm after a conversion formula.